# AWS Lambda; Modifications to the version or the alias?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm a little confused about whether I should modifying my lambda alias or the version to which the alias references.

I see that you can modify the "provisioned concurrency" and "asynchronous invocation" from both the alias and the version. you can also "add trigger" to both the alias and the version. however adding a trigger to the alias does not actually seem to add it to the version.

When do  you modify  the version and when do you modify the alias and why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambda **versions** are considered to be **immutable snapshots** of your function. Thus, if you use the version of your function in a clients code (e.g. API gateway, some end-user applications) then you are guaranteeing that the function code along with its other parameters (e.g., env parameters) are fix and will never changed.

You can adjust some of their parameters (async options, triggers), but never its code. So you use versions when you are absolute sure that you will never modify its code. In this case, in any client application you will be using **ARN of function version** (not alias nor $latest) and then you will use triggers and async settings for this version only version. Other version of the same function can have different triggers and async values.

**Aliases** on the other hand are like pointers. They can **point to different versions** of a function. Therefore, you are going to use **ARN of function alias** in your client's code when you expect to keep modifying and upgrading your function with time. In this case, you just change the alias to point to new function version when its avaiable, without the need to modify any client application. Thus, you should modify alias async settings and triggers if you use aliases in your client's code. The reason is that the triggers and async option will **persist** regardless of function version currently being pointed to by an alias.